# Interactive map does not seem to be filtering data properly (Shiny, Leaflet)

Tags: r, shiny, leaflet, interactive

I've built an interactive map to filter Toronto Auto Thefts by day of the week and year. However, I've been looking at the map that gets built and it does not seem as if the data is being filtered at all. It looks like the same points get plotted every input change.

I'm not sure what is not working considering the code looks fine. Here is what I have:

```
data <- structure(list(occurrenceyear = c(2017L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 
                                          2018L, 2018L, 2017L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L), occurrencedayofweek = structure(c(7L, 
                                                                                                                       6L, 7L, 3L, 3L, 8L, 2L, 7L, 8L, 7L), .Label = c("", "Friday    ", 
                                                                                                                                                                       "Monday    ", "Saturday  ", "Sunday    ", "Thursday  ", "Tuesday   ", 
                                                                                                                                                                       "Wednesday "), class = "factor"), Lat = c(43.7639694, 43.5895691, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                 43.6753197, 43.7586555, 43.727829, 43.6431503, 43.6683502, 43.6842308, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                 43.6707535, 43.6820869), Long = c(-79.1886063, -79.5458221, -79.3138199, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   -79.4392548, -79.4406738, -79.5390091, -79.3820572, -79.4840012, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   -79.3930817, -79.4356079)), row.names = c(NA, 10L), class = "data.frame")

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Toronto Auto Thefts"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput("checkGroup", h3("Weekday"), choices = list("Monday" = 1,
                                                              "Tuesday" = 2,
                                                              "Wednesday" = 3,
                                                              "Thursday" = 4,
                                                              "Friday" = 5,
                                                              "Saturday" = 6,
                                                              "Sunday" = 7), selected = 1),
      selectInput("checkGroup2", h3("Year"), choices = list("2014" = 1, 
                                                            "2015" = 2, 
                                                            "2016" = 3, 
                                                            "2017" = 4, 
                                                            "2018" = 5), selected = 1),

    ), 
    mainPanel (leafletOutput("map", "100%", 500))
  ))

server <- function(input, output, session){
  output$map <- renderLeaflet({
    df <- data[data$occurrencedayofweek == input$checkGroup & data$occurrenceyear == input$checkGroup2]
    leaflet() %>%
      addTiles() %>%
      addCircles(data = df)

  })

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is data a dataframe? If so, you need a comma, here:

```
data[data$occurrencedayofweek == input$checkGroup & data$occurrenceyear == input$checkGroup2, ]
```

You've got quite a few problems in your example.

- Typos between `data` and `df`
- Whitespace in your level names
- Your input choices don't correspond properly to your data

I think this addresses them all:

```
library(shiny)
library(leaflet)

df <- structure(list(occurrenceyear = c(2017L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 
                                          2018L, 2018L, 2017L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L), occurrencedayofweek = structure(c(7L, 
                                                                                                                       6L, 7L, 3L, 3L, 8L, 2L, 7L, 8L, 7L), .Label = c("", "Friday    ", 
                                                                                                                                                                       "Monday    ", "Saturday  ", "Sunday    ", "Thursday  ", "Tuesday   ", 
                                                                                                                                                                       "Wednesday "), class = "factor"), Lat = c(43.7639694, 43.5895691, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                 43.6753197, 43.7586555, 43.727829, 43.6431503, 43.6683502, 43.6842308, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                            43.6707535, 43.6820869), Long = c(-79.1886063, -79.5458221, -79.3138199, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   -79.4392548, -79.4406738, -79.5390091, -79.3820572, -79.4840012, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   -79.3930817, -79.4356079)), row.names = c(NA, 10L), class = "data.frame")
df$occurrencedayofweek <- trimws(as.character(df$occurrencedayofweek))
df$occurrenceyear <- as.character(df$occurrenceyear)



ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Toronto Auto Thefts"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput("checkGroup", h3("Weekday"), choices = c("Monday",
                                                              "Tuesday",
                                                              "Wednesday",
                                                              "Thursday",
                                                              "Friday",
                                                              "Saturday",
                                                              "Sunday"), selected = 'Monday'),
      selectInput("checkGroup2", h3("Year"), choices = 2014:2018, selected = 2017)

    ), 
    mainPanel (leafletOutput("map", "100%", 500))
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$map <- renderLeaflet({
    df <- df[df$occurrencedayofweek == input$checkGroup & df$occurrenceyear == input$checkGroup2,]

    leaflet() %>%
      addTiles() %>%
      addCircles(data = df)

  })
}


shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: I've made that change, but now none of the points are showing up on the map...

Comment: It's hard to offer more assistance without a sample of your data.

Comment: I've updated the code above with a sample of the data.